# How do I diagnose (New)TweetDeck refusing to display specific updates in the Home column?

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

I'm trying to figure out why TweetDeck's Home column consistently fails to show me the updates of a single account I follow from one of mine. Various notes:

- Yes, I'm sure. The [problem account](https://twitter.com/questionheds) is the *only* one I'm following from mine, so the omission is obvious. For all I know, I'm missing all sorts of other stuff, but my other accounts have enough follows I haven't noticed.
- If I add a dedicated Timeline column for my account, the Questionheds updates *do* display there. I would like not to do this, for clutter reduction.
- This is not due to filters:

  - I don't have a source filter for what they're using(Twitterfeed).
  - There's no way my content filters would catch every single one of the updates.
  - I have no author filters set up.
- …but I went ahead and added a filter against Twitterfeed just to make sure, at which point the timeline column hid them, as expected. Then I removed the filter, obviously.
- And anyway filters are global so it wouldn't explain why I can see the updates in a timeline column.
- The behavior duplicates across both the desktop and Chrome apps.
- I also confirmed using someone else's TweetDeck account.
- It does not duplicate on the old AIR version of TweetDeck, though granted it doesn't have a combined "home"-style column for direct comparison.

I'm running out of ideas. Is there something I'm missing?
If one or two people using this client could temporarily follow Questionheds and confirm in comments, even that might be useful. (I'm completely unaffiliated with Questionheds.)

I'm open to removing all filters, but would really like to avoid it as long as possible. There are a *lot* of source/client filters and the new interface makes them really tedious to re-add. Though again, note above that they are not likely a factor, and the other person whose account I tried doesn't have my filters, obviously.